# Active Merchat Paypal Access Token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I'm using active merchant to interact with paypal, and I need offline access of users' paypal account. E.g. send money on their behalf asynchronously.

Is it possible to keep an access token from Paypal, and authenticate with that instead of storing the user's paypal email and password?

Rails 3 + Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Active Merchant gem but in general yes - you can use the PayPal Permissions Service API to collect authorization from a merchant (as an access token) to make API calls on behalf of them. You can find more details about the API here: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/permissions